# A type of traversal (pattern match) in gremlin

Tags: sparql, gremlin

*Note: My background is in sparql, and i'm learning Property Graph and Gremlin. Just started the journey*

There is one particular type of traversal that so far i am not seeing how to express very well.

The type of traversal is selecting a set of matching start node, based on how they connect to a path or a set of node along a path of multiple node.

Simple example would be:

Finding all the person that like a message that has been twitted by an Organization.

In sparql it would be something akin to

```
?p a Person .
?p likes ?msg .
?msg a Message .
?msg twitted_by ?Org .
?Org a Organization .
```

Can someone show me how to express this is Gremlin. And as i keep learning, maybe point me some tutorial that would help me grasp how to write this kind of traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm, not familiar with SPARQL syntax,
but from your description I think you looking for something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").where(
        out('likes').hasLabel('Message').
        out('twitted_by').hasLabel('Organization')
    )
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ywp5cd33un

I'd recommend you to learn Gremlin from Kevin Lawrence's book [PRACTICAL GREMLIN](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html)

Comment: Super nice thank you. Gremlify as a tip awesome too. thanks. I guess the key here is the *where step*. So many thanks.

Comment: BTW, does BackFilterPipe still exist or was it remove, found it in a turorial, but is not a step in the official doc ....

Comment: in the doc for the where step they say the anonymous traversal in the where is processed locally ? Locally, i think i get it, however, what is an anonymous traversal, is it like an anonymous function in scala.

Comment: @MaatDeamon I think the BackFilterPipe is no longer part of the gremlin API, at least it's the first time I heard about it... the anonymous traversal is a traversal inside of the  brackets, meaning it is not chained to the main traversal

Comment: It does not start with a global index right ? The input of the anonymous traversal is the local node ? Example in the where close ? I mean like in scala u can pass the input parameter implicitly and I wonder if it is what happens here ?

Comment: I don't know how they implement it, but yes it starts at the same point at the traversal as before the step that uses it.